# Редактировать задачу в todo list js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, помогите тут плиз, я постоянно дорабатываю тудушку и вот мне нужно сделать возможность, чтобы можно было редактировать таск, ну у меня почему-то не получается, я пытался по разному создавать из разных источников, но не один не помогал, тут скорее всего я что-то не так делал, заранее спасибо, вот код:

```js
//1) создаю три главных переменных, которые подключаются к основным html функционалом туду листа
const addTask = document.getElementById('add-task');
const inputTask = document.getElementById('task-input');
const allTasks = document.querySelector('.all-tasks');
const delAll = document.getElementById('delete-all-tasks')

let tasks = [];
let todoTasks = [];

/*
if (!localStorage.tasks) {
  tasks = []
} else {
  tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
}*/


//2) создаю функцию-конструктор, которая поможет создать много однотипных объектов
function Task(task) {
  this.task = task;
  this.completed = false;
}

//6) создаю функцию, где будет сам таск
function createTask(description, index) {
  return `
        <div class="create-task ${description.completed ? 'checked' : ''}">
             <div class="task">${description.task}</div>
             <div class="action">           
                  <input onclick="completedTask(${index})" class="complete" type="checkbox" 
                        ${description.completed ? 'checked' : ''}>
                  <span onclick="editTask(${index})" class="btn-edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></span>
                  <span onclick="deletedTask(${index})" class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></span>
             </div>
        </div>          
    `
}


//9) создаю функцию, которая будет фильтровать завершенные таски и опускать их вниз
function filterTasks() {
  const activeTasks = tasks.length && tasks.filter(item => item.completed === false);
  const completedTasks = tasks.length && tasks.filter(item => item.completed === true);
  tasks = [...activeTasks, ...completedTasks];
}

//5) создаю функцию, в которой таски будут выводится на странице
function showTasks() {
  allTasks.innerHTML = "";
  if (tasks.length === 0) {
    delAll.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    delAll.classList.remove("hide");
  }
  if (tasks.length > 0) {
    filterTasks();
    tasks.forEach((item, index) => {
      allTasks.innerHTML += createTask(item, index)
    });
    todoTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.create-task');

  }
}

showTasks();

//4) создаю функцию, где я буду обращаться к locale storage, чтобы хранить там таски
function storage() {
  //localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
}

//7) создаю функцию, которая будет отвечать за завершения таска
function completedTask(index) {
  tasks[index].completed = !tasks[index].completed;
  if (tasks[index].completed) {
    todoTasks[index].classList.add('checked')
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.success('Task done!')
    }, 150)
  } else {
    todoTasks[index].classList.remove('checked')
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.warning('Task not done!')
    }, 150)
  }
  storage();
  showTasks();
}


//8) создаю функцию, которая будет отвечать за удаления таска
function deletedTask(index) {
  todoTasks[index].classList.add('deleted')
  setTimeout(() => {
    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    storage();
    showTasks();
  }, 500)
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertify.success('Task deleted!')
  }, 550)

}

function editTask() {

}


//3) создаю нажатие на кнопку добавить новый таск
addTask.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputTask.value === '') {
    alertify.error('Enter a task!')
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.success('Task added!')
    }, 100)
    tasks.push(new Task(inputTask.value));
  }
  storage();
  showTasks();
  inputTask.value = '';

});

//10 создаю нажатие на кнопку, которая удаляет все таски
delAll.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertify.success('All tasks deleted!')
  }, 100)
  tasks = [];
  storage();
  showTasks();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.todo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.add-todo {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-task {
  width: 80%;
}

.input-task input {
  width: 425px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.add-task-button {
  width: 95px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: aqua;
}

.add-task-button button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-task-button button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.create-task {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.create-task.checked {
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.create-task.deleted {
  animation: 1s slidein;
}

.create-task.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.task {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
}

.action {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.action input {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.action span {
  color: #B71C1C;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.action span:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

.action span.btn-edit {
  color: #1A237E;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.action span.btn-edit:hover {
  color: darkcyan;
}

.del-all-tasks-button button {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: cursive;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  /* user-select: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
     */
}

.del-all-tasks-button button:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.del-all-tasks-button button.hide {
  display: none;
}

.input-edit {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  display: none;
}

.input-edit.edit {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.noactive {
  display: none;
}

input-edit:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.txt {
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* .btn-edit {
    background-color: #00537e;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .btn-edit:hover {
    background-color: #033953;
  } */
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<h1>ToDo List</h1>
<div class="todo">
  <div class="add-todo">
    <div class="input-task">
      <input type="text" id="task-input" placeholder="What needs to be done today?">
    </div>
    <div class="add-task-button">
      <button id="add-task"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <h2 style>Tasks for the day:</h2>
  <div class="all-tasks"></div>
  <div class="del-all-tasks-button">
    <button id="delete-all-tasks">Clear All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сниппет не позволяет использовать `LocalStorage`, так что я их закомментировал.

Comment: `filterTasks` не проще ее через sort сделать?)

Comment: А как ты его через sort сделаешь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактирование таска происходит следующим образом:
При нажатии на кнопку "редактировать", вместо теста таска появляется инпут с этим текстом, который можно изменить.
При повторном нажатии на кнопку "редактировать", значение с инпута заменяется в массиве и вместо инпута появляется текст.

```js
//1) создаю три главных переменных, которые подключаются к основным html функционалом туду листа
const addTask = document.getElementById('add-task');
const inputTask = document.getElementById('task-input');
const allTasks = document.querySelector('.all-tasks');
const delAll = document.getElementById('delete-all-tasks')

let tasks = [];
let todoTasks = [];

/*
if (!localStorage.tasks) {
  tasks = []
} else {
  tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'))
}*/


//2) создаю функцию-конструктор, которая поможет создать много однотипных объектов
function Task(task) {
  this.task = task;
  this.completed = false;
}

//6) создаю функцию, где будет сам таск
function createTask(description, index) {
  return `
        <div class="create-task ${description.completed ? 'checked' : ''}">
             <div class="task">${description.task}</div>
             <div class="action">           
                  <input onclick="completedTask(${index})" class="complete" type="checkbox" 
                        ${description.completed ? 'checked' : ''}>
                  <span onclick="editTask(${index})" class="btn-edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></span>
                  <span onclick="deletedTask(${index})" class="delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></span>
             </div>
        </div>          
    `
}


//9) создаю функцию, которая будет фильтровать завершенные таски и опускать их вниз
function filterTasks() {
  const activeTasks = tasks.length && tasks.filter(item => item.completed === false);
  const completedTasks = tasks.length && tasks.filter(item => item.completed === true);
  tasks = [...activeTasks, ...completedTasks];
}

//5) создаю функцию, в которой таски будут выводится на странице
function showTasks() {
  allTasks.innerHTML = "";
  if (tasks.length === 0) {
    delAll.classList.add("hide");
  } else {
    delAll.classList.remove("hide");
  }
  if (tasks.length > 0) {
    filterTasks();
    tasks.forEach((item, index) => {
      allTasks.innerHTML += createTask(item, index)
    });
    todoTasks = document.querySelectorAll('.create-task');

  }
}

showTasks();

//4) создаю функцию, где я буду обращаться к locale storage, чтобы хранить там таски
function storage() {
  //localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
}

//7) создаю функцию, которая будет отвечать за завершения таска
function completedTask(index) {
  tasks[index].completed = !tasks[index].completed;
  if (tasks[index].completed) {
    todoTasks[index].classList.add('checked')
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.success('Task done!')
    }, 150)
  } else {
    todoTasks[index].classList.remove('checked')
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.warning('Task not done!')
    }, 150)
  }
  storage();
  showTasks();
}


//8) создаю функцию, которая будет отвечать за удаления таска
function deletedTask(index) {
  todoTasks[index].classList.add('deleted')
  setTimeout(() => {
    tasks.splice(index, 1);
    storage();
    showTasks();
  }, 500)
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertify.success('Task deleted!')
  }, 550)

}

// Редактирование таска
function editTask(index) {
  let curTask = todoTasks[index]; // выбранный таск
  if(!curTask.classList.contains('edit')) { // При первом нажатии на кнопку редактирования, начинаем редактировать.
    curTask.classList.add('edit'); // Добавляем класс 
    curTask.querySelector('.task').innerHTML = `<input type="test" value="${tasks[index].task}">`; // Вместо задачи добавляем инпут с редактированием
  } else { // При втором нажатии, когда класс `.edit` есть, мы сохраним
    let newTask = curTask.querySelector('.task > input').value;
    tasks[index].task = newTask;
    curTask.querySelector('.task').innerText = newTask;
    curTask.classList.remove('edit');
    // storage();
  }
}


//3) создаю нажатие на кнопку добавить новый таск
addTask.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputTask.value === '') {
    alertify.error('Enter a task!')
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alertify.success('Task added!')
    }, 100)
    tasks.push(new Task(inputTask.value));
  }
  storage();
  showTasks();
  inputTask.value = '';

});

//10 создаю нажатие на кнопку, которая удаляет все таски
delAll.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alertify.success('All tasks deleted!')
  }, 100)
  tasks = [];
  storage();
  showTasks();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.todo {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.add-todo {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.input-task {
  width: 80%;
}

.input-task input {
  width: 425px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.add-task-button {
  width: 95px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  color: aqua;
}

.add-task-button button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: aqua;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.add-task-button button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.create-task {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.create-task.edit {
  background-color: #90eee1;
  border-color: #005b64;
}

.create-task.edit .btn-edit {
  background: green;
}

.create-task.checked {
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.create-task.deleted {
  animation: 1s slidein;
}

.create-task.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.task {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
}

.action {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.action input {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.action span {
  color: #B71C1C;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.action span:hover {
  color: darkred;
}

.action span.btn-edit {
  color: #1A237E;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.action span.btn-edit:hover {
  color: darkcyan;
}

.del-all-tasks-button button {
  background-color: #B71C1C;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: cursive;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  /* user-select: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
     */
}

.del-all-tasks-button button:hover {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.del-all-tasks-button button.hide {
  display: none;
}

.input-edit {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  display: none;
}

.input-edit.edit {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.noactive {
  display: none;
}

input-edit:focus {
  color: #333;
}

.txt {
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.btn-edit {
  background-color: #00537e;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.btn-edit:hover {
  background-color: #033953;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"></script>

<h1>ToDo List</h1>
<div class="todo">
  <div class="add-todo">
    <div class="input-task">
      <input type="text" id="task-input" placeholder="What needs to be done today?">
    </div>
    <div class="add-task-button">
      <button id="add-task"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <h2 style>Tasks for the day:</h2>
  <div class="all-tasks"></div>
  <div class="del-all-tasks-button">
    <button id="delete-all-tasks">Clear All</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно работает. Но тут получается, что только два действия идет, нажимаешь редактировать, отредактировал, нажал обратно и все, если ты еще раз захочешь отредактировать, то оно не будет работать, пока страницу не перезагрузить, как это исправить?
Также там класслист edit, это его нужно создать или он уже где-то есть, а то я что-то его не нашел в стилях.

Comment: Забыл его удалить после сохранения таска. Класс `edit` используется для проверки, но вы в стилях можете указать для этого класса любые значение, например менять цвет фона редактируемого таска, либо менять кнопку "редактировать" на "сохранить", например.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделал там всё как положено, добавил стили, сделал, чтобы редактировалось всегда при нажатии, спасибо еще раз

Comment: @АндрейХотюн, не за что. Если мой ответ вам помог, то отметьте его галочкой (слева-сверху от ответа)